# play framework using slick with java

Tags: java, playframework, slick

I want to start a new play framework project, and I want to use a database mapper. 
For Scala there is slick.

Can I use Slick with java as well? Or is there a nice pendant for java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward answer is *no*. You may be using it in Scala (eg. write DAO layer in Scala) and then use that in your Java but honestly it may be too much of a hustle.

There is no straightforword alternative - you would need to use `Hibernate` or `Ebean`.

Comment: Okay Thanks And what so you think about querydsl?

Comment: Dou you probably have an example project with a java controller and persisting with slick?

Comment: I don't have an example. As for `querydsl` - never used it, but it's looking good. As for Java world - it seems the closest to `Slick` concepts from what I have seen.